# Spring boot Rabbitmq configuration for a remote queue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I need to configure my app in order to send and consumes messages from/to a queue sitting on on anoter server. I have the following configuration in **my application.properties:**

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=amqp://cloudamqp.com/...
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=jpkszgmu
spring.rabbitmq.password=***********************
```

**And in my controller:**

```
@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@RequestMapping
public void send(@RequestParam String expediteur, @RequestParam String destinateur, @RequestParam String contenu){

    int i = 1;
    SMS s = new SMS("SMS00"+i, expediteur, destinateur, contenu);
    this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(MeService.queueName, s);
}
```

**And the listener:**

```
@RabbitListener(queues = queueName)
public void process(@Payload SMS s){
    System.out.println("SMS Recus: "+s.toString());
    r.send(s);
}
```

However I am getting errors saying the 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rabbitTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException..

any help?

**Full Trace of the error**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'meController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rabbitTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "//jpkszgmu:1VfGR2I6AmJ7D8ySJU7PdFKJLf085wkI@penguin.rmq.cloudamqp.com/jpkszgmu:5672"

**UPDATE 3**

ERROR 8392 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:367) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:565) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1135) [spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1200(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:96) [spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1380) [spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:381) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:909) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:799) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:351) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:571) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    ... 1 common frames omitted

Comment: This has nothing to do with the broker being remote; you have something missing from the class path. You need to edit your question to show the complete information (exactly what the unsatisfied dependency is).

Comment: @GaryRussell See the updated version..

Comment: That's not the full stack trace.

Comment: I have solved that issue by changing the host to "penguin.rmq.cloudamqp.com".. And the error changed.. please check the new update on the questions..

Comment: I think delete the queue and restart the application again it will recreate the queue with correct attributes...Usually we will get this error if the queue properties(auto-delete,durable etc) are not matched....

Comment: @VelNaga thanks, that worked..!! but now it is saying java.net.UnknownHostException: penguin.rmq.cloudamqp.com/jpkszgmu

Comment: It's strange...Could you please post the stacktrace...Also please check your remote host URL...

Comment: IT IS WORKING NOW!! the value I was giving to the host was to be given to the ** spring.rabbitmq.addresses **  instead..

Comment: Great...Could you please accept my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think delete the queue in RabbitMQ admin and restart the application again it will recreate the queue with correct attributes...Usually we will get this error if the queue properties(auto-delete,durable etc) are not matched....