# Error: Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s)

Tags: rabbitmq

Running my Docker image, this error is coming up:

```
2021-May-12 04:03:02.327 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - [] Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s). 
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2089)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2062)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2042)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:407)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:391)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1859)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1840)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1200)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1137)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1087)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:560)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:533)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:487)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: For future visitors, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471538/spring-boot-rabbitmq-configuration-for-a-remote-queue

Comment: Did you use the correct username and password to connect to RabbitMQ? The error message says `Connection refused`, it seems like that RabbitMQ service has started, but cannot accept your connection.

Comment: Could you add more information? when does this happen? all the time, only at startup, after restarting rabbitmq service?

Comment: I had the same problem. I was using the wrong port for the conection. That was the only problem.